# Error while installing PHP expect extension

Tags: php, expect, php-extension, pecl

I got some serious error while installing expect extension in PHP.

I ran `sudo pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/expect-0.3.1`

I got error like this while running make,

```
running: make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootvXp7LZ/expect-0.3.1/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/expect -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootvXp7LZ/expect-0.3.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootvXp7LZ/expect-0.3.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/expect -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/expect/expect.c -o expect.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/expect -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootvXp7LZ/expect-0.3.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootvXp7LZ/expect-0.3.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/expect -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/expect/expect.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/expect.o
In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/expect/expect.c:21:0:
/tmp/pear/temp/expect/php_expect.h:33:17: fatal error: tcl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [expect.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Please advice me as I am a very beginner in PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you need to install TCL libraries in your Unix box :-?

Comment: I installed TCL-DEV with this command `apt-get install tcl-dev`

Comment: And getting same error !

Answer (score 4):

I found [this](https://github.com/Juniper/netconf-php/blob/master/INSTALL.md) post helpful for this issue.  On CentOS I was able to get this installed via:

```
yum install tcl tcl-devel tk tk-devel 
yum install expect expect-devel
pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/expect-0.3.1
```

Then add the following to php.ini:

```
extension = expect.so
```